# Background image top portion gets hidden under browser bookmark bar

Tags: html, css

The background image gets under the"bookmark bar" of the chrome browser, due to which the top portion of the image is not seen. Is there a way, we can ensure the image fits exactly to the screen of the browser display ?

My CSS code:

```
body {
 background: url("http://localhost/img/BackgroundImage.png") no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Just align the background top the top?

Comment: This generally happens when you use `background-size: cover`. Try using a image with appropriate image size.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the suggestion squeamish ossifrage and Vibhor Dube.
I increased the background image size to 1600 X 703. It fits in perfect..